# What are Advanced Dog Tags

Tags: battlefield-3

In Battlelog, the list of dog tags is split up into "Basic Dog Tags" and "Advanced Dog Tags".

So far (Rank 13) all dog tags I have unlocked were "Basic Dog Tags". I started out with the BF:BC2, the N7 and the Mass Effect 3 advanced dog tags, like everyone, I guess.

So: **What are Advanced Dog Tags, and how do you unlock them?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you scroll over them you can actually see the description of each tag and how to get them

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't try this ^^ Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Advanced Dog tags are unlocked through doing special things that are much harder than just leveling up.

For example, unlocking all the unlocks for a vehicle class, or getting your first "x" medal. Advanced dog tags also keep track of stats most of the time.

The only advanced dog tags that comes from leveling up comes at levels 40 through level 45 and then every now and again (like 10+ levels) to 145.

Comment: Ah... now I understand what you mean by the dog tags "keeping track of my stats": The inscription on the tag changes while you progress (without having to earn the tag over and over again or something like that) Thanks!

Comment: @SealedSun The ones unlocked through leveling or pre-order bonus's etc don't keep track of stats. I think only the ones gotten through unlocking medals or service stars do.

Answer (score 3):

You also get advanced tags if attained a mastery, like I have and advanced tag for rifle kill, and also saviour, revives, avenger etc. these are just some there are many more. There are also advanced tags for pre-order Amazon orders, Dr Pepper coupons and Back To Karkand and some other stuff.